# Are Category or Tag Archive Pages Possible?

Tags: categories, templates, tags, template-redirect

Currently /category and /tag 404 if you hit them directly. Is it possible to create a theme template to handle what would display on it? Mark Jaquith - http://twitter.com/#!/markjaquith/status/154324264047218688 - mentioned it might be possible to do with a custom rewrite rule, but I don't know where to begin to implement such a thing... Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely possible. By default, the category archive page will be at domain.com/category/the_category. The file that is typically used for this rendering is `category.php`, which is located in your theme directory.

To remove the /category/ part, so that your category archives are at domain.com/the_category, you can use the [SEO Ultimate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-ultimate/) plugin. After installing the plugin, go to "Permalink Tweaker" and check the first box.

See more at the [Codex: Category Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) page.

Comment: I'm trying to include this functionality in http://tersustheme.com. Was really hoping to avoid a plugin if at all possible. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Why are you avoiding plugins? The SEO Ultimate plugin is widely used and vetted.

Comment: Plugins = cruft. The point of Tersus is to simplify. :) If we could make this work without plugins, I think it'd make for a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

It possible to create your own template called category-archive or tag-archive

Wordpress uses archive template pages which are pretty much always included in any Wordpress theme.

Checkout your theme folder and then check the Wordpress Codex ( follow the link from Gavin above ) ... for examples of category or tag template pages. You can even have specific templates for different categories if you really want to be complex.

The plugins mentioned above will help for SEO but it sounds to me like you want your own template page.